# PALO ALTO SSL VPN with Mac OS X client

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, ssl

I am trying to connect an OS X client to a Palo Alto SSL VPN.

The standard net connect tool does not support OS X but I'm wondering if anyone has had any sucess with any third party applications for SSL VPN on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the standard NetConnect client on Mac OSX and it works fine. Actually, I find it works better than the Windows client a lot of the time.

Comment: I didn't realise there was a OSX client, can you provide a link?

Comment: I installed mine directly from the Palo Alto I connect to. Just open a browser on your Mac and put the url of your firewall in the address bar. When you log in it should install from there.

Comment: Awesome Palt-Alto must have done some upgrades, this didnt work 12 months ago!!